# How can the effect of electric and magnetic fields on the motion of a particle be distinguished?

Tags: electromagnetism

It's a conceptual question about magnetic field: Suppose a charged particle moves under the influence of an electric and a magnetic field, how do we distinguish the effect of the fields on the motion of the particle?

Answer (score 1):

We can very well distinguish between magnetic and electric fields by simply observing the movement of a charged particle.

As it was said correctly, the magnetic field does not do any work on the particle, meaning it does not accelerate it linearly. It does however apply a force that is *perpendicular* to the direction of motion. To illustrate, we assume a particle that moves in the x-direction in a homogenous magnetic field in the y-direction. As you surely know, the Lorentz force is given by $$\vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B$$, meaning that the force acts in the z-direction on the particle (which we for now assume to be positive). What will happen is that the charge will follow a circular path in that magnetic field.
A beautiful experiment is to use electrons in a Helmholtz coil pair (two large coils with a certain separation that creates a nearly homogenous magnetic field in the center):

[image]

Consider a homogenous electric field as a contrast: the force on the charge is given by $$\vec F = q \vec E$$ and is clearly directed in the direction of the electric field and not at right angles to it. In the simple case of $\vec v$ going in the same direction as $\vec E$, the charge will be accelerated. If it is at right angles, the charge will be deflected, just as you can imagine in the case of a horizontal throw in a homogenous gravitational field.

[image]

Depending on how you are allowed to prepare the experiment, it becomes fairly simple to see what effects the magnetic or electric fields have on a charge.

It must be noted, however, that electricity and magnetism are of course strongly interrelated, and the above discussion breaks down if you assume moving inertal frames. Special relativity connects those phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we know the position $x(t)$ and the velocity $\dot x(t)$ of the particle on an interval of time $t$, and that we know the only force is the Lorentz force. Can we completely determine the electric and magnetic field at any point of the arc of trajectory?

## Non-relativistic case

We will prove that at any point of the trajectory,

- we can determine the component of the electric field tangent to the trajectory;
- we cannot determine the component of the magnetic field tangent to the trajectory;
- knowing two of the field components perpendicular to the tangent to the trajectory allows to know the remaining two.

Let's introduce the arclength $s$, Frenet basis $(T, N, B)$, and the curvature $\rho$:

$$\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \dot{s}T,\\
\ddot{x} &= \ddot{s}T+\rho\dot{s}^2N.
\end{align}$$

For the electric and magnetic field, I will use the subscripts $t$, $n$ and $b$ to denote their components in Frenet basis. Newton's law

$$m\ddot x(t)=q(E+\dot x(t)\times B).$$

then reads

$$m(\ddot{s}T+\rho\dot{s}^2N)=q(e_tT+e_nN+e_bB+\dot{s}(b_nB-b_bN)),$$

i.e.

$$\begin{align}
e_t &= \frac{m}{q}\ddot{s},\\
e_n-\dot{s}b_b &= \frac{m}{q}\rho\dot{s}^2,\tag{1}\\
e_b+\dot{s}b_n &= 0.\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

QED.

## Relativistic case

Let's prove the following:

- Same conclusions as for the non-relativistic case.

The right-hand side of Newton's law does not change while its left-hand side becomes $\dot{p}$ with $p=m\gamma\dot x$ but

$$\gamma = (1-\dot{s}^2)^{-1/2}.$$

Therefore

$$\dot{p} = m\gamma^3\ddot{s}\dot{x} + m\gamma\dot{x}.$$

Thus we can reuse the non-relativistic analysis by adding a term $m\gamma^3\ddot{s}\dot{s}T$ and replacing $m$ by $m\gamma$ everywhere else. Thus

$$\begin{align}
e_t &= \frac{m}{q}\gamma\ddot{s}(1+\gamma^2\dot{s}),\\
e_n-\dot{s}b_b &= \frac{m}{q}\gamma\rho\dot{s}^2,\tag{1}\\
e_b+\dot{s}b_n &= 0.\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

QED.

Answer (score -1):

The magnetic field does no work on the particle and hence its energy remains constant. The effect of the electric field changes its energy.

Comment: Well then the question is how does the particle's energy affect the motion? Can you connect the two here?